# Running Emacs withing cygwin: charsets directory not found

Tags: linux, emacs, cygwin

I have installed cygwin with the all of the emacs packages (I think?). Whenever I try to open emacs within the cygwin terminal, I receive the message,

```
Warning: arch-dependent data dir 
'/usr/libexec/emacs/25.1/x86_64-unknown-cygwin/': No such file or        

directory
Warning: arch-independent data dir '/usr/share/emacs/25.1/etc/': No such 

file or directory
Warning: Lisp directory '/usr/share/emacs/25.1/lisp': No such file or    

directory
Error: charsets directory not found:
/usr/share/emacs/25.1/etc/charsets
Emacs will not function correctly without the character map files.
Please check your installation!
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install a font set. (such as Deja Vu Font family)
I had the same error, found this question and not much else on the issue.  I then guessed to fonts, and installed that font family.

I also installed some LaTeX fonts, and a few other things; but I think it was the DeJaVu fonts that got it to work.